the pdf did not rerender in the react memo component when parameter changed
I am trying to use react pdf to render some pdf, to avoid the resouce waste, I am using use memo to decide the pdf rerender when pdf url changed. This is the App.tsx:
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Page } from 'react-pdf';
import { Document } from 'react-pdf';
import { DocumentCallback, Options, PageCallback } from 'react-pdf/dist/cjs/shared/types';
import { pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';
import 'react-pdf/dist/Page/TextLayer.css';
import styles from './App.module.css';
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${pdfjs.version}/build/pdf.worker.min.js`;

interface PDFPreviewProps {
  curPdfUrl: string;
}

const App: React.FC<PDFPreviewProps> = React.memo(({curPdfUrl}) => {

  const canvasArray = useRef<Array<React.MutableRefObject<HTMLCanvasElement | null>>>([]);

  const handlePageRenderSuccess = (page: PageCallback) => {

  };

  const options: Options = {
    cMapUrl: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@${pdfjs.version}/cmaps/`,
    httpHeaders: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + "getAccessToken()"
    }
  };

  const docuemtLocadSuccess = (pdf: DocumentCallback) => {

  }

  const updateRefArray = (index: number, element: HTMLCanvasElement | null) => {
    if (element) {
      canvasArray.current[index] = { current: element };
    }
  };

  const handlePageChange = (page: any) => {

  };

  const renderPages = (totalPageNum: number | undefined) => {
    if (!totalPageNum || totalPageNum < 1) return;
    const tagList: JSX.Element[] = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= totalPageNum; i++) {
      tagList.push(
        <Page key={i}
          scale={1}
          onLoad={handlePageChange}
          canvasRef={(element) => updateRefArray(i, element)}
          onChange={handlePageChange}
          onRenderSuccess={handlePageRenderSuccess}
          pageNumber={i} >
        </Page>
      );
    }

    return tagList;
  }


  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.rightPart}>
        <Document options={options}
          file={curPdfUrl}
          onLoadSuccess={docuemtLocadSuccess}>
          {renderPages(1)}
        </Document>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  let shouldRerender = prevProps.curPdfUrl !== nextProps.curPdfUrl;
  return shouldRerender;
})

export default App;

in the outer component, I added a button to change the pdf url like this:
import { useState } from "react";
import App from "./App";
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Home.module.css";

const Home: React.FC = () => {

    const [pdfUrl, setPdfUrl] = useState<string>("");

    const changePdfUrl = () => {
        let url = [
            "https://pdf.top/tex/static/proj/2023/9/287ea73d1c78463298e9e5b267cab87f/main.pdf?v=ba9e5b5fda754e72a20",
            "https://pdf.top/tex/static/proj/2024/5/aaeaa9e3e51c49f28a05ea6ce93d897f/main.pdf?v=510abe62dc315ace1f9"
        ];
        let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        let pdf = url[idx];
        console.log(idx);
        setPdfUrl(pdf);
    }

    return (
        <div className={styles.home}>
            <button onClick={() =>{changePdfUrl()}}>btn</button>
            <App curPdfUrl={pdfUrl}/>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Home;

when I click the outer level compoent button, the pdfUrl will random change. What I expect is that when the pdf url changed the same, the pdf will not be rerender, when the url changed, the react-pdf component will change the pdf to the new one.
But when I click the button to change the pdf url, the remo component will never changed. Am I missing something? what should I do to make it work as expect? This is the package.json:
{
  "name": "react-demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "config-overrides-path": "src/config/config-overrides.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@codemirror/commands": "^6.2.4",
    "@codemirror/state": "^6.2.1",
    "@codemirror/view": "^6.16.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@textea/json-viewer": "^2.16.2",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.2.6",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.21",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.30",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.4",
    "bootstrap": "v5.3.1",
    "eventsource": "^2.0.2",
    "mocha": "^10.4.0",
    "rd-component": "0.1.56",
    "rdjs-wheel": "0.0.26",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-pdf": "^7.3.3",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.5.0",
    "rollup-plugin-visualizer": "^5.9.2",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "vite": "^4.4.7",
    "vite-plugin-svgr": "^3.2.0",
    "vite-plugin-top-level-await": "^1.3.1",
    "vite-plugin-wasm": "^3.2.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "dev": "vite --host=0.0.0.0 --port=3000"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/eventsource": "^1.1.11",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.5.6",
    "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}


The arePropsEqual function defined for your memoized component returns false if the old and new props are equal.
According to the docs, it should return true if the old and new props are equal instead.
You should have:
//...
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  return prevProps.curPdfUrl === nextProps.curPdfUrl;
})

